# Typescript - ReturnType from nested arrow function

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a type that describes an object with a nested function:

```
type EntitiesGetters = {
  getCategories: (state: EntitiesState) => (panelID: EntityID) => CategoryGroup;
};
```

and here is an example of applying this type to an object:

```
export const entitiesGetters: EntitiesGetters = {
  getCategories: (state) => (panelID) => {
    const data = {} as GET_TYPE;

    for (const key in state.categories) {
      const category = state.categories[key];
      if (category.entities.panel === panelID) {
        data[Object.keys(data).length] = category;
      }
    }

    return data;
  },
};
```

How can I get the type I need in GET_TYPE (which corresponds to the type "CategoryGroup")?

**Еither correct me if I'm using the wrong approach.**

Comment: Are you getting an error? You want to mark `data` as having type `CategoryGroup` am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: What happens when you replace `GET_TYPE` with `CategoryGroup`?

Comment: There will be no error, but would it be good practice? (
I'm new to TS, so I apologize for possibly stupid questions))

I assumed that it was possible to somehow substitute it dynamically (e.g. ReturnType) so that all the necessary types were described in a separate place from the function body.

Comment: If you control all the types, I don't think it would be considered bad parctice. Otherwise, you should probably check out @Bbrk24's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the TypeScript builtin `ReturnType`:

```
export const entitiesGetters: EntitiesGetters = {
  getCategories: (state) => (panelID) => {
    const data: ReturnType<ReturnType<EntitiesGetters["getCategories"]>> = {}

    // ...

    return data;
  },
};
```

Comment: The know the return type, don't they? What's the advantage of this over `const data: CategoryGroup = {}` except for not having to change it should the return type ever change?

Comment: @isaactfa i think the advantage is you don't need to know of the existance of `CategoryGroup` (or more practical maybe you are using a library that exports `EntitiesGetters` but not `CategoryGroup` so you can't use the latter)

Comment: just what I was looking for, thanks a lot!